# .pic.yml debugger not found in VSCode

Tags: yaml

## [picyml debugger not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvnAD.png)

Hello,
I am trying to run a file with .pic.yml extension for gdsfactory project, but as soon as I hit run, the error prompt opens up. The 'gdsfactory' extension and plugins are installed in VSCode. What could be the reason for the error and how could I solve this?

I tried to run the file and view it in klayout live.